# Why am I getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet error?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, dispatcher

I am trying to learn Spring MVC. So far I have done the following:

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                        id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>SpringMvc</display-name>
      
      
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>
             org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
          </servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>
       
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    
    </web-app>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
                        
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.awesomememe"></context:component-scan>
    
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
                    
    
</beans>
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package com.awesomeme.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    
    public String showHomePage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("message","Smrita is awesome");
        return "home";
    }

}
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
        Message from the controller is 
        <h1>${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And my directory structure looks as follows:

[image]

And I have added the following jars :

[image]

But when I try to run the app I get the following error:

[image]

[image]

What exactly am I missing. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: right click the project >Java Build path >Add external jars

Comment: Well I am using eclipse IDE

Comment: Make sure you have them in your deployment assembly.

Comment: You have to keep the Jars in WEB-INF\lib.

Comment: the context loader is also missing

Comment: I hate Eclipse internal build system for that reason ... Maven would be nicer in jar dependencies : it automatically cares for transitive dependencies, and **automatically** put all required libs in war under `/WEB-INF/lib` so that the container finds them at runtime. As you don't use it, **you** have to care for both ...